# What does it mean for an ODE to be unchanged?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've seen it claimed that Euler's equation $$x^2y^{\prime \prime} +axy^\prime +by =0$$ is scale invariant and thus unchanged unchanged under $x \to \alpha x$. However, replacing $x$ with $\alpha x$ yields the equation:

$$\alpha^2x^2y^{\prime\prime}+a\alpha x y^\prime +by=0$$

What does it mean to say this equation is unchanged from the original equation? Furthermore, in what does it mean to say an arbitrary ODE is unchanged under $x \to \lambda x$, $y \to \lambda^{\alpha}y$, and how can I determine for which value of $\alpha$ this holds?

Comment: Chain rule error. $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} y(\alpha x) = y'(\alpha x) \cdot \alpha \text{.} $$

Comment: Do you have a reference that the Cauchy-Euler equation is invariant under scaling of the independent variable?  I'm used to the claim that it is invariant under the change of variable $x \mapsto \mathrm{e}^u$.

Comment: $$x^2\frac{dy^2}{dx^2}+ax\frac{dy}{dx}+by\leftrightarrow \alpha^2x^2\frac{dy^2}{d(\alpha x)^2}+a\alpha x\frac{dy}{d\alpha x}+by$$

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my error, it seems obvious now. My reference is these notes: http://www-thphys.physics.ox.ac.uk/people/AlexanderSchekochihin/ODE/2018/ODELectureNotes.pdf (section 5.1.4)